# Lightning: Datatable not displaying decimal values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

What is the type to display the decimal values in Lightning datatable?
number type is not displaying values in lightning:datatable.

Answer (score 5):

For your decimal column, use

```
var columns = [
    { label: 'Decimal Column', fieldName: 'theFieldName', type: 'number',
      typeAttributes: { maximumFractionDigits: '2' }
    }
];
```

Check out the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) under "Formatting with Data Types" for more info.